# Issue in implementing infinite retry in kafka consumer

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka 2.2.8 and trying to implement infinite retry policy using AlwaysRetryPolicy and I've created a custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler to capture the exception, message key and value during deserialization.

Here is my consumer config code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class MyKafkaConsumerCommonConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {
        private final MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler mySeekToCurrentErrorHandler;
        private final MyRecoveryCallback myRecoveryCallback;
        private final MyKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy myKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy;

        @Autowired
        public MyKafkaConsumerCommonConfig(
            MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler mySeekToCurrentErrorHandler,
            MyRecoveryCallback myRecoveryCallback,
            MyKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy myKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy) {

            this.mySeekToCurrentErrorHandler = mySeekToCurrentErrorHandler;
            this.myRecoveryCallback = myRecoveryCallback;
            this.myKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy = myKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy;
        }

        @Bean
        public <K,V> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
          ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
          factory.setConsumerFactory(primaryConsumerFactory());

          // To achieve Stateful Retry
          factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
          factory.setErrorHandler(mySeekToCurrentErrorHandler);

          // Retry Template
          factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());

          //Recovery Call back
          factory.setRecoveryCallback(myRecoveryCallback);

          return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Object> primaryConsumerFactory() {
          return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(getConfigs());
        }

        public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            retryTemplate.setListeners(new RetryListener[]{myKafkaRetryListener});
            retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(myConsumerRetryPolicy);

            ExponentialBackOffPolicy exponentialBackOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
            exponentialBackOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("MY_KAFKA_RETRY_BACK_OFF_IN_MILLIS", "500")));

            //As per the spring-kafka documentation, maxInterval (60000 ms) should be set less than max.poll.interval.ms (600000 ms)
            exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("MY_KAFKA_MAX_RETRY_BACK_OFF_IN_MILLIS", "60000")));
            retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(exponentialBackOffPolicy);

            return retryTemplate;
       }

       public Map<String, Object> getConfigs() {

           Map<String, Object> configs = = new HashMap<>();

           configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

           configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
           configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);

           configs.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, stringDeserializerClass);
           configs.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, kafkaAvroDeserializerClass.getName());

           sapphireKafkaConsumerConfig.setPartitionAssignmentStrategyConfig(
               Collections.singletonList(RoundRobinAssignor.class));

           // Set this to true so that you will have consumer record value coming as your pre-defined contract instead of a generic record
           sapphireKafkaConsumerConfig.setSpecificAvroReader("true");
         }
}
```

Here is my code for custom RetryPolicy and custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.

```
@Component
public class MyKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy {

  private final Environment environment;

  public MyKafkaConsumerRetryPolicy(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("MY_KAFKA_RETRY_COUNT", "3")));

    this.setExceptionClassifier(classifiable ->
    {
      // Always Retry when instanceOf   MyCustomException
      if (classifiable.getCause() instanceof MyCustomException) {
        return new AlwaysRetryPolicy();
      } else if (classifiable.getCause() instanceof DeserializationException) {
        return new NeverRetryPolicy();
      } else {
        return simpleRetryPolicy;
      }
    });
  }
}



@Component
public class MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {

  private final MyLogger logger;

  @Autowired
  public MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler(MyLogger logger) {

   super(-1);

    this.logger = logger;
  }

  @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> data,
        Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {

  if(thrownException instanceof DeserializationException){

    // This portion would be executed when there is DeserializationException
    final String messageKey = (String) data.get(0).key();

   logger.logException(thrownException, "DeserializerException occurred for  message key"+messageKey, getClass());

    System.out.println("messageKey is "+messageKey);
    System.out.println("message Value is "+data.get(0).value());

    //TODO: Send message to DLT
  } else {

   //Calling super method to let the 'SeekToCurrentErrorHandler' do what it is actually designed for
    super.handle(thrownException, data, consumer, container);
  }
}
```

As you can see above, I'm setting the max attempts to '-1' in my custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler constructor. Now, to test this, I'm throwing MyCustomException in my consumer which should pick the AlwaysRetryPolicy and trigger infinite retry. But it's retrying only 10 times and stopping. Please suggest, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `} else if (classifiable.getCause() instanceof DeserializationException) {`

That will never happen that far up the stack; deserialization exceptions are passed directly to the container's error handler. You already have code in your error handler for that case.

2. `super(-1);`

That should work; use a debugger; set a breakpoint in `FailedRecordTracker.skip()` to see if `this.maxFailures` is 10; if it is -1, it should always return `false`.

**EDIT**

Here's a simpler version of what you have (Spring Boot app) and it works as expected:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So60641945Application {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So60641945Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60641945Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorHandler eh() {
        class MyEH extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {

            MyEH() {
                super(-1);
            }

            @Override
            public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                    MessageListenerContainer container) {

                LOG.info("handle");
                super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
            }

        };
        return new MyEH();
    }

    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60641945", topics = "so60641945")
    public void listen(String in) {
        LOG.info(in + this.count.incrementAndGet());
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so60641945", 1, (short) 1);
    }

}

@Component
class FactoryConfigurer {

    FactoryConfigurer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new AlwaysRetryPolicy());
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOff = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOff.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOff);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
    }

}
```

and

```
2020-03-11 15:53:23.497  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so60641945] Setting newly assigned partitions [so60641945-0]
2020-03-11 15:53:23.519  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo1
2020-03-11 15:53:24.521  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:24.526  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo2
2020-03-11 15:53:25.527  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:25.529  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo3
2020-03-11 15:53:26.534  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:26.537  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo4
2020-03-11 15:53:27.539  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:27.541  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo5
2020-03-11 15:53:28.542  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:28.546  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo6
2020-03-11 15:53:29.549  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:29.552  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo7
2020-03-11 15:53:30.553  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:30.555  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo8
2020-03-11 15:53:31.559  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:31.561  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo9
2020-03-11 15:53:32.562  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:32.564  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo10
2020-03-11 15:53:33.568  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:33.571  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo11
2020-03-11 15:53:34.572  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:34.574  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo12
2020-03-11 15:53:35.577  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:35.580  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo13
2020-03-11 15:53:36.582  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:36.584  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo14
2020-03-11 15:53:37.587  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : handle
2020-03-11 15:53:37.589  INFO 30480 --- [o60641945-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60641945Application   : foo15
...
```

**EDIT2**

Embedded kafka:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class So60641945ApplicationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embedded = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws InterruptedException {
        this.template.send("so60641945", "bar");
        Thread.sleep(30_000);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the response. I'm sure I'm getting it as -1 but will debug again.

Comment: I debugged this and it's returning false in FailedRecordTracker.skip() but stopped retrying after 10 attempts not sure why

Comment: There is something very strange going on if that is really happening. We always perform the seeks when `skip()` returns false. If you can put together a small sample app that exhibits this behavior, I'll take a look.

Comment: sure, I'll try and might take sometime for me. Thank you.

Comment: In the meantime, I added a simpler example of what you have to the answer and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: I tried all possible combinations including below one but didn't work. factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(-1)); Just to re-iterate, I'm using spring-kafka-2.2.8-RELEASE.

Comment: My test was written with Spring Boot 2.1.13/Sping Kafka 2.2.12 - as I have said to you before, it's best to keep up to date with the latest version in your minor release even if you can't move up to a more recent minor or major release for some reason; 2.2.8 is over 6 months old. That said, I downgraded the project to 2.1.7/2.2.8 and it **still works the same way (infinite retries)**. I can't reproduce your issue. You must be doing something wrong; but I can't guess what that is without seeing the complete project (or preferably a small one that exhibits the behavior you are seeing).

Comment: Can you please post your code which is producing the message so that I can simulate the same and see what's happening with my configuration

Comment: `$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic so60641945` then `>foo`.

Comment: ok, i'm trying to use the EmbeddedKafkaRule to spin up a in-memory kafka for my tests.

Comment: I just added a test with an embedded broker and it still works fine for me; see the edit.

Comment: ok, even the test is not working for me and getting "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available." error. Let me create a sample app and will send that code.

Comment: I copied the whole project to a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/d19cfd6a0e3545768707c9d0ad794856

Comment: i got it working.. missed something earlier and modifying that to have my consumer config

Comment: Finally, I figured out the issue and it's because of the Exponential BackOff Policy I was using and I changed it to Fixed Backoff Policy and it started working. I updated my question to reflect the backoff policy config I've. Now, I've to figure out why Exponential BackOff policy is causing the issue